# rails survey - tracking when already answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, survey

I've just implemented a simple model in my app, to create a survey. Simple question and some answer.

There is no need to be connected to answer the survey, but I want people to answer it just one time. How can I do that?

I don't know how to track this easily: IP, user agent etc. But these things can be easily changed. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way of doing this. You can only rely on the information sent by the user, but user can tweak this data any way he wants before the request is sent. Also, you don't want to block the whole machine - what about internet cafes then? The only way which will kind of do what you want is to place a pernament cookie on the client's browser, (but those also can be removed).

Comment: I see, so the more efficient way to do this is by place a permanent cookie on the browser ? There is a simple way to do this in rails ?

Comment: It is very simple in rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: If you send the survey by email you could provide them a unique link. Just in case you do so